# Set Shortcut key for vim for Sorting all of the blocks of parent-child in .vimrc

Tags: sorting, vim, tags, block

I want to set shortcut key to my vim editor(like php storm) for sorting all of the blocks of parent-child(tags) in html or other programming languages!

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When i press `ctrl`+`alt`+`z`,My `*.html` file sorted like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible? If it's, what should i add to my `.vimrc`?

I remember when i used phpstorm, we had shortcut key for such things!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open the text in vim, try this:

```
"if your file is with name foo.html this step can be skipped
:set ft=html (press enter) 
gg=G
```